# Extension domains for $W^{1,2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I'd like to have some hints for a problem I bumped into some times ago but I was not able to solve (even if I think the most is done...).

---

Before the problem, let me recall some *definitions.* 
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a nonempty open set (*n.o.s.*, for short) and consider the Sobolev space $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ (which is Hilbert's with its *natural* inner product $\langle u,v\rangle := \int_\Omega u\ v+\nabla u\cdot \nabla v$).

$\Omega$ is called an *extension domain* (*for $W^{1,2}$*) iff there exists a function $P:W^{1,2}(\Omega) \to W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ (usually called *extension operator*) s.t.:

1. $P$ is linear;
2. $Pu\Big|_\Omega = u$ a.e. in $\Omega$ for all $u\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$;
3. there exists a constant $C=C(\Omega)$ s.t. $\lVert Pu\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)} \leq C\ \lVert u\rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}$ and $\lVert Pu\rVert_{W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N)} \leq C\ \lVert u\rVert_{W^{1,2}(\Omega)}$ for all $u\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$.

For example, if $\Omega$ is a n.o.s. and $\partial \Omega$ is sufficiently smooth (e.g. Lipschitz) then $\Omega$ is an extension domain (cfr. [Brezis](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=GAA2XqOIIGoC&oi=fnd&pg=PP6&dq=brezis%20functional%20analysis&ots=srjzR5G_fY&sig=CLIkgZqT6sIJGk5q38PzMGfSiKM#v=onepage&q=brezis%20functional%20analysis&f=false), 9.2).

---

And here we go.

> Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a n.o.s. and assume that for each $u\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ there exist some $U\in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ s.t. $U\Big|_\Omega =u$ a.e.
>
> Prove that $\Omega$ is an extension domain.

Moreover, the following hint was given in the lecture:

> Use the Hilbert space structure of $W^{1,2}$.

Actually, the problem here lies in finding a good candidate to be the extension operator $P: W^{1,2}(\Omega) \to W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N)$. In order to find such a $P$, I thought to proceed as follows.

For each $u\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ I set:
$$K_u := \left\{ U \in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N) |\quad U\Big|_\Omega =u \text{ a.e.}\right\} \; ;$$
it is easily seen that $K_u$ is a *nonempty closed convex set* in $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N)$, hence there exists a *unique* $\tilde{u} \in K_u$ having minimal norm and it is characterized by the *variational inequality*:
$$\tag{V}\forall U\in K_u,\qquad \langle \tilde{u} ,\tilde{u} -U\rangle \leq 0\; .$$
Now, $\tilde{u}$ seems to be a good candidate to be the extension of $u$ I'm looking for, therefore I set:
$$P:W^{1,2}(\Omega) \ni u \mapsto \tilde{u} \in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^N)$$
and I have to show that such a $P$ satisfies properties **1**, **2**, **3**.

**1**. *$P$ is linear*. First of all, I note that $K_{\alpha u} =\alpha\ K_u$; thus $P(\alpha u) =\widetilde{\alpha\ u} =\alpha\ \tilde{u} =\alpha\ Pu$ follows from (**V**) and $P$ is *homogenous*. It remains to prove that $P$ is *additive*, i.e. that I get $P(u_1+u_2)=Pu_1+Pu_2$ for all $u_1,u_2\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$. For $W\in K_{u+v}$ I have $W-\tilde{v} \in K_u$, $W-\tilde{u} \in K_v$ therefore:
$$\langle \tilde{u} +\tilde{v}, \tilde{u} +\tilde{v}-W\rangle =\langle \tilde{u} , \tilde{u} - (W -\tilde{v})\rangle +\langle \tilde{v} , \tilde{v} - (W -\tilde{u})\rangle \leq 0 \; ,$$
thus $P(u+v) =\widetilde{u+v} =\tilde{u} +\tilde{v} =Pu+Pv$.

**2**. $Pu\Big|_\Omega = u$ *almost everywhere*. This comes from $Pu=\tilde{u} \in K_u$.

> But now I'm in trouble in proving **3**... Any hints?

Comment: Maybe 3. follow from the closed graph theorem.

Answer (score 2):

That is, indeed, a Baire category game. You have a linear mapping $P$ from one Hilbert space to another. Note that the pre-image of every closed ball centered at the origin is closed (indeed, if $u_j\to u$, and $\|Pu_j\|$ are bounded by $R$, then some subsequence of $Pu_j$ converges to something weakly but that something restricted to $\Omega$ must be $u$ and its norm is at most $R$, so $\|Pu\|\le R$ by the construction. Now, the union of those pre-images is the entire space, so one of them has an inner point, which is enough to conclude that $P$ is a bounded linear mapping.